Automated sprint capacity organization
I've tried to figure out if there is a conceivable way to accomplish this with automation but I'm coming up with nothing.  This is a frequent issue within my org causing massive amount of frequent rework for PO's and issues with too many jira queries.
Lets say I have a team with a capacity of 40 pts per sprint and I have 480 points of work divided into 12 sprints.  Now I realize Jira isn't a forecasting tool, but tell that to upper management.  So it's critical I keep my sprint's up to date.  Lets say I loose 8 points of capacity in the next sprint. Currently I am manually shifting 8 points into and out of each sprint to balance my new capacity.  It would be great if there was an automated way of accomplishing this across a specified range of sprints, allocating a target amount of points per sprint, without disrupting the story order.

The problem is trying to do long-term planning in a complex environment that is full of ambiguity and uncertainty.
The use of terms like "PO" (for "Product Owner") and "Sprint" make it seem like Scrum is in use. However, this is not Scrum as it is defined. It's also not Agile, as it appears to favor planning and following a plan over responding to change.
There are a series of problems with having 12 Sprints worth of work.
It took a lot of time to get the work into a state that is ready for development, from eliciting the requirements from stakeholders to decomposing the work to sizing the work. This work is now inventory - the team has invested time and energy (and money) into something that is going to sit around and wait.
As the team starts to do the work and get feedback from the stakeholders, the team will learn. The team will learn more about the problems and the domain, architectures and designs will emerge, and the team gets more clarity about what is needed and wanted. These things that are learned will cause previously undiscovered work to emerge, work previously thought to be necessary to be invalidated, new and better ways to decompose the work, and changes in the effort of completing necessary work. The plan will change.
The passage of time will also affect the work. The stakeholders and their environment will change. This will make some work unnecessary, other work needed, and shuffle the priorities and value associated with work. Regular feedback from your stakeholders will allow you to make these changes.
Your plan is also based on a consistent ability to do work. Over time, the team should strive to improve its ways of working. Retrospectives are the only practice called out in the Manifesto for Agile Software Development. Hopefully, these retrospectives lead to improvements. However, there may also be positive or negative impacts outside of the team's direct control. Basing a plan on something that is known to be highly variable results in a plan with very little meaning.
If you don't want to take an agile or adaptive approach to planning, then you will have to deal with the rework of planning. But this isn't functionality built into Jira, and tool recommendations are off-topic here. If you're operating in a complex environment, the best course would be to educate your stakeholders on better ways of working rather than building and buying complex solutions to artificially-induced problems.

You are not wrong.  Unfortunately there is not much I can do about it.  Executives love to throw out the term agile, while changing nothing about the way business is done and metrics are being collected.  This is a form of agile called SAFe, which caters to quarterly program implementations, long term planning. I'm not a big fan of it but it's what I have to work with

@mreff555 You should edit your question body and tags to include references to SAFe. However, that doesn't change most aspects of my question. Even within SAFe, you do not plan your Iterations within your PI in detail at the PI Planning - at least, that's not what the SAFe framework calls for. You typically leave capacity for the unknown when allocating features to iterations at PI Planning. You don't say what your role is, but if it's the SAFe Scrum Master/Team Coach, RTE, or SPC, then you should be in a position to coach the organization through these changes and shifts.

Added.  I am a product owner.  There are teams within our program that do this and it frequently leads to issues.  My team approaches a new project with SWAG's for features.  Over the next few weeks we fill in the gaps with stories and eventually comprehensive information including story points for each story.  Leaving them in the backlog isn't an option because that feature is a deliverable with a contractually obligated date, with many other features as prerequisites.  High level estimates are vague and generally don't respond well to inevitable scope creep. They never work out for me.

@mreff555 Now you're getting to the heart of the problem. You lose slack in the schedule when you stack up contractually obligated deliverables into a series of dependencies. This slack is how teams handle complexity, uncertainty, and ambiguity. Your commitments and lean-agile methods are at odds, but we know that lean-agile principles actually work. You're asking how to do big up-front planning, but we have decades of experience that say big up-front planning doesn't work. Also, what you call "scope creep" may not be scope creep, but an improved understanding of what needs to happen.
